# Catch specific exception

Tags: python

In my function, if `text_content` is e.g. German, the function fails. With the current solution I get back:

```
print(type(e))
>>> <class 'google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument'>
```

I wanted to be more specific and wrote instead `except Exception as e:` `except InvalidArgument as e:` However, that doesn't work. Dou you have an idea what's wrong here?

```
text_content= "Trauben sind gut. Bananen sind schlecht."
try:
    sample_analyze_entity_sentiment(text_content)
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e))
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What exactly happens?

Comment: What doesnt work? your generaral try/except or implementing InvalidArguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the `InvalidArgument` exception.

```py
from google.api_core.exceptions import InvalidArgument

text_content= "Trauben sind gut. Bananen sind schlecht."
try:
    sample_analyze_entity_sentiment(text_content)
except InvalidArgument as e:
    print(type(e))
```